# Valor mínimo de uma lista dentro de outra lista python

Tags: python, lista

Olá.

Tenho uma situação que consegui resolver, fazendo loops. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de simplificar o que fiz, usando lambdas ou outro recurso da linguagem.

Tenho uma lista e dentro dela uma outra lista, conforme abaixo:

```
import numpy as np

lista=[]
lista.append([0.21, np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.667]), 2, 0])
lista.append([0.98, np.array([0.7, 0.9, 0.552]), 1, 1])
lista.append([0.05, np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.552]), 1, 3])
lista.append([1.18, np.array([0.7, 0.9, 0.552]), 1, 0])
```

preciso armazenar em um outro vetor a lista que contenha o menor valor da primeira posição, que no caso seria a terceira lista [0.05, np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.552]), 1, 3].
Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
mins = lista[0][0]
tmp= lista[0]
vetorfinal =[]
for j in range(len(lista)):
    if lista[j][0] < mins:
        tmp= lista[j]
        mins = lista[j][0]
vetorfinal.append(tmp)
```

Consegui resolver de uma forma não muito usual. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de ser feito com menos linha de códigos.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível utitlizar a função interna `min`, especificando a chave da comparação (neste caso o primeiro elemento de cada sequência):

```
import numpy as np

lista=[]
lista.append([0.21, np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.667]), 2, 0])
lista.append([0.98, np.array([0.7, 0.9, 0.552]), 1, 1])
lista.append([0.05, np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.552]), 1, 3])
lista.append([1.18, np.array([0.7, 0.9, 0.552]), 1, 0])


print(min(lista, key=lambda x: x[0]))
#[0.05, array([0.5  , 0.5  , 0.552]), 1, 3]
```